# How did I have access to Suggested Edits without 2k rep?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was clicking through my profile and noticed I had received the Custodian badge 4 times (once per review type), and one of these was for "Reviewing Suggested Edits". It says that I had [rejected a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23544077) on one of my answers. However, at no point have I ever had over 2K rep so it seems like there should be no reason for me to have ever had access to the review queue. Furthermore, clicking "next task" gives me the standard "you can't access this till 2k rep" message.

What happened here, and why did I have the ability to reject an edit?

Comment: I believe this is a dupe, but you can review edits to your own posts regardless of your rep.

Comment: If anybody suggests an edit on your post, you can approve or reject it. It might happen that you override them without noticing if you had started an edit. In that case, when you save the post, the pending suggestion is automatically rejected.

Comment: It looks like someone else edited my post, but I've had other posts of mine edited in the past and I never had the option to approve/reject said edits. I'm just curious what the case was that caused this particular scenario. (Ah, I hadn't seen your edit when i was typing my comment. That makes sense!)

Comment: Go to your profile → Activity → All actions → Reviews. On page 4, you'll find a ["reject"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23544077) "Proposed Jul 16 '19 at 20:21". Maybe you just don't recall it :)

Comment: If a user with more than 2k rep makes an edit, it's in effect immediately. Otherwise, it's a *suggested edit* that has to be approved either by two reviewers or by the post author.

Answer (score -2):

Solved. The author of a post may approve/reject an edit on their own post.